# Re-restricting permissions to Documents directory (to only its user in Windows) after moving it (onto another NTFS partition)

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs, home-directory

I moved a user's `Documents` folder (let's call the user "Beta") to a separate partition by going to the user's `My Documents` folder, `right-clicking`, selecting `Properties`, clicking on the `Location` tab, entering `D:\data` as the new directory, and then clicking `Move...`.

*However, the new directory is accessible to all users*, including the Guest user. **I would like this `Documents` folder in its new location to be accessible to only that user**, Beta.

Details:

- I am using Windows 7 Pro.
- My internal harddrive has various partitions. Windows is on `C:`, the largest partition (for all my working files) is `D:`, and there will be more partitions for Linux.
- The only Administrator is called Alpha.
- Beta is the user whose new location for his Documents folder is `D:\data`.
- There is another non-admin user, Gamma. Gamma should not have access to `D:\data`.
- The Guest user should also not have access to `D:\data`.

The existing "Group or user names" in the Security tab of that folder's Properties window are: `Authenticated Users`, `SYSTEM`, `Administrators (nameofmycomputer\Administrators)`, and `Users (nameofmycomputer\Users)`. I do not know what these mean.

As I understand, I would want `D:\data` to have the same permissions as the original `C:\Users\Beta\Documents`. How can I achieve this?

Bonus: I would like future installations of Linux on additional partitions to have access to `D:\data`. That is, the access restriction mechanism should be something enforced by the OS, Windows, but not by encryption. (More complicated and powerful solutions are welcome too; if you would like, I can later ask a separate question for such answers, which you can first give here. However, I am first and foremost interested in a simple, non-hacky solution that gets me up and running quickly.) Actually, it seems like Linux generally ignores NTFS permissions; but any confirmation of this will be welcome as well.

Note: It seems like permissions are changed using the commands `takeown`, `icacls`, or `cacls`, but I am looking for expert advice from someone with experience on this issue, lest I break anything.

Comment: PS: I understand that a lot of questions along the lines of "how to move my home/documents folder" have been asked and answered on the web, but what I care about is a simple fix to the permissions issue based on the simplest solution ("Locations -> Move...") to the "different location for home folder(s)" problem.